# Items arrive as undefined at child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-props

using the quasar framework with Vue 3, I am experiencing the following issue:

Whenever I try to pass variavles/objects/arrays or whatever from a component to another, regardless of what methos I use (provide/inject and props in the 'script setup' mode or export in the 'script' mode), in the child component I get unknown or undefined when trying to print the received item to the console. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Here is a simple example:

```js
// parent component:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { provide } from 'vue'
const nums = [1, 2]
provide(nums, 'numbers')
</script>

// child component: 
<script setup lang="ts">
const numbers = inject('nums')
console.log(numbers)
</script>


// I also tried 
// parent:
<script setup lang="ts">
const nums = [1, 2]
</script>

// child:
<script setup lang="ts">
import parent from './parent.vue'
import { PropType } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  numbers: {
    type: Array as () => number[],
    required: true
})
console.log(props.nums)
```

Comment: Can you please show the template with the props try ?

Comment: The template in empty as I just wanted to access a parent's array in a child component and print it to the console from there. Here is the code with the template:                            <template>
  <div>My component</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { provide } from 'vue'
const nums = [1, 2]
provide(nums, 'numbers')
</script>

Answer (score 0):

According to vue documentation:

> The `provide()` function accepts two arguments. The first argument is called the *injection key*, which can be a string or a Symbol. The injection key is used by descendant components to lookup the desired value to inject.
> The *second argument* is the provided value. The value can be of any type, including reactive state such as refs

```
const nums = [1, 2]
provide(
  'numbers', /* the key callable via child components */
  nums,      /* value */
)

// child component
const numbers = inject('numbers')

<template>{{ numbers }}</template>
```

Here's the playground [demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/BXLl4AUJSq9lbQSVJWAAyDghjmkybZ1SWzLj1Apyr+zdtq0Qig378x4d/bR0julksYBndHMFJorSwxYpxZM8FpJbUlLlJYNL4F0ZKNlTSKUR7cDv9zxqjwySRoin9ArmCikMJYIVxsyJ5+TmNx8efiY8SpCZg3aRHHQXDORpb0LrI+BhVpVuQWMCMn6SikGWTowNKbWYJkN3yZ7IwU20no1o4WsFa9AvyjL0QajMxIYz+VVJX+eAma1g/iEFzsovv/B9+bgMUZfNRjQDTA6cDbXW7A9vXp/hgO+B7KWpatQPUK+gZGV8x572b0TJdq+0AW3j2HcXGw/zOpgQZhTU96oV3ZBzygOfznS+tnuNJmGf0x0OMVhc2OnwMUeCvv3Ei727Lc571Xn7Y7tNdtNFg+ADfYpC+8iSxFEypf2pvt8UJImrxwYkq0XbXuqRrouS9fhKLz+8jS6X2sd+Mo=)

Comment: Thanks for providing the code in the playground. Unfortunatuly the template showing anything but the content of the numbers array. Here is the output I get: Hello from child
injected values

Comment: @GhazalNikmanesh can you share the playground?

Comment: Of course! Where do you want me to share it?

Comment: If it's too complex to run on Vue's Official SFC playground, then I'd suggest to share it via [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com). I'd like to try fixing it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The issue is already solved. I was making the silly mistake of implementing the child instead of the parent into the page I wanted to display the whole thing from!

Answer (score 0):

To complete the previous answer, here is a way of passing `num` variable to a child component through props :

ParentComponent.vue

```js
<template>
  <ChildComponent
   :num="num"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'

const num = [1, 2]
<script>
```

ChildComponent.vue :

```js
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  num: Array
})

console.log(props.num) // [1, 2]
</script>
```

Note that `defineProps()` doesn't need to be imported, as specified in the doc : https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits :

> the defineProps and defineEmits APIs, which are automatically available inside

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunatuly this doesn't work neigher for me. The type of the number array is still unknown to the child component. This is what VS code shows me as type: const props: {
    readonly nums?: unknown[] | undefined; Maybe there is a problem with the configuration, eg. JSON packages??? I really have no clue.
}

Comment: I made a mistake that I've just corrected. I forgot the `setup`attribute in script tag. Was it missing on your side ? It seems to me that it could also comes from Typescript.

Comment: No, no! The code is correct. It was an implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
// parent component:
provide('numbers', nums)

// child component: 
const numbers = inject('numbers');  // with the same key as in parent
```